# Doctrine behavioral extensions: Loggable with Timestampable

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-extensions

As I understand from the [docs](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md), you can get a full history of changes on an entity with Loggable as long as it is configured as \Versioned in the entity. I was wondering if this log history retains also a timestamp of the changes? If not, is it possible to combine with Timestampable to get a full history with timestamp? Or should I add a timestamp field that I \Versioned and manage myself?

I want to know what and when a certain entity changed.

What would be a good approach to this problem?

Comment: I needed to track changes for my app and as a general rule, I add a time field for most of my entities.  I have an admin section and made my own [eventlistener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762100/iterating-through-doctrines-changeset) that checks when specific entities are updated, then it does a second check for certain cases if specific fields are updated.  This way I am only logging what I need.  Using Loggable will create a very large database overtime and may be necessary if you want to roll back.  The key is to try to log what you need which is why I made my own listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity/MappedSuperclass/AbstractLogEntry.php#L35

Is `loggedAt` property an answer for your question?